# How to change TableViewer header's font and Style

Tags: swt, jface

I'm using Viewer Framework in my Eclipse RCP application, i would like to show table header a little large compared to table rows,when i set font to the table, it's applied to the entire table,i would like to show table header unique and highlighted with a separate Font and color that's different from table rows.

I used `viewer.getTable().setFont();` to set Font but it sets font to whole table(including headers)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You say that `Table.setFont()` also changes the font of the headers. On which platform does that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is currently [not supported](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=63038).